# CRM 2015 SSRS report run in VS, page is blank in CRM

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

This makes no sense so I'm totally grasping here. Does anyone have any idea why an SSRS report .rdl runs wonderfully in VS preview, but then when published to CRM, the page is blank? I see the "building report" spinning indicator, then the screen is blank for first page. There is a second page to the report and that page looks great.

This is a context sensitive report. It works for just 1 out of 8 records. What is happening?

I don't even know the first step in debugging this :-/

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most common problem with SSRS in the past (before SSRS 2016) was a browser not rendering report elements at times in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, or Safari.  It could deal with the way the element tablix, grid, list, or other web parts are displayed.  I would advise end users to use IE or download IE tab.  The way to make it work on a server is pretty painstaking to the point I would say just upgrade to SSRS 2016.  The first step of debugging SSRS hosted report problems though is seeing how they look in different browsers.  Microsoft again redid SSRS completely with 2016 and it is much better IMHO.

Comment: This is a government on-prem CRM 2015. You can't just say "you need to upgrade" :-/

Comment: That ignores the first three sentences of what I wrote.   Good luck buddy.

Comment: No I read it all and I appreciate the reply a lot :-) I'm just a bit hand-cuffed in terms of downloading and installing software. Sorry if my comment was terse.